# Flutter TextField Ipad Chinese input, selection always on top

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ipad, flutter-layout

[image]

The Chinese letter selection always on the left top corner, when iPad connects to the external keyboard.

```
   body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(child: TextField()),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/zhangjunyi/Develop/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (3 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/zhangjunyi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/zhangjunyi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` is deprecated now....
In your `Scaffold`, set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` property to `false`.

This should solve your issue.

Comment: thanks, but the property only fix the widget not overflow by the on-screen keyboard. Only find this issue, when using the Chinese input method, text selection.

Comment: I made some research and seems like there's a lot of bugs with Chinese input method. Is it bugging on both iOS and Android?

Comment: only appears on iPad with an external keyboard